# relative path instead of absolute path in java

Tags: java, path, relative-path

```
public String[] return_login_config_array(String name, int index) {
    SPACE_CreateThroughExcel create = new SPACE_CreateThroughExcel();
    String[][] data = create.read(name);
    int columns = data[0].length;
    String[] login_var = new String[columns];
    for (int i = 1; i < columns; i++) {
        login_var[i] = data[index][i];
    }
    return login_var;
}
```

When calling this function I have to mention the entire path `C:/Users/Rachana/workspace/SPACEOM/WebContent/Data/login.xlsx`.

But I want to mention only the relative path wrt to the directory I am working in.

The function path `C:/Users/Rachana/workspace/SPACEOM/src/com/srishti/space_om/SPACE_Functions.java`

Comment: What happens in the `create.read` method? If you need relative paths (related to your working directory) than just specify the relative path, e.g. `WebContent/Data/login.xlsx` when `C:/Users/Rachana/workspace/SPACEOM` is your working directory.

Answer (score 0):

If your "login.xlsx" is in the same package as SPACE_Functions.java class else you need append relative path before it.

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("login.xlsx ");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

Else try to map the path to java class

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/<relative path>/login.xlsx ");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

If you need this in a servlet then use `getServletContext().getRealPath("/filepathInContext")`

or use java.net.url

```
java.net.URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("web.xml");
String filePath = url .getFile();
```